# SKPhysicsJointPin in a side scrolling Swift SpriteKit game

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, side-scroller, skphysicsjoint

I'm trying to develop a side scrolling game in SpriteKit. My problem is the following:

- I'm trying to add a rope to my game, but it breaks when I start the game.  When I add this rope to a non-scrolling game it works perfectly well. I think the problem is from the scene anchor point or something but I just can't figure it out. I have already a week of this "hard work". I have a SKNode named "world" and all the objects are attached to it and I move the "world" to the left and I center the "camera" on my player and so the player moves to the right and all the other objects are left behind.

Here is my code:

- Here is the function for the "world"

  ```
  override func didSimulatePhysics() {
     centerOnNode(ball)    
  }

  func centerOnNode(node: SKNode) {
     positionInScene = convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: node.parent!)
     world.position = CGPointMake(world.position.x - positionInScene.x + 100, world.position.y)
  }
  ```
- And here is the function for the rope

  ```
  let length = 5
  let startPosition = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
  var chains : [SKNode] = []

  func addChain() {

      let chainHolder = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "chainHolder")
      chainHolder.position = startPosition

      chains.append(chainHolder)
      world.addChild(chainHolder)

      chainHolder.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: chainHolder.size.width / 2)
      chainHolder.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

      for i in 0..<length {

          let chainRing = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "chainRing")
          let offset = chainRing.size.height * CGFloat(i + 1)
          chainRing.position = CGPointMake(startPosition.x, startPosition.y - offset)
          chainRing.name = String(i)

          chains.append(chainRing)
          world.addChild(chainRing)

          chainRing.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: chainRing.size)
      }

      for i in 1...length {

          let nodeA = chains[i - 1]
          let nodeB = chains[i]
          let joint = SKPhysicsJointPin.jointWithBodyA(nodeA.physicsBody, bodyB: nodeB.physicsBody,
              anchor: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(nodeA.frame), CGRectGetMinY(nodeA.frame)))

          /*var pt = CGPointMake(world.position.x, world.position.y);
          pt = convertPoint(pt, fromNode: world);

          pt.x += scene.size.width * scene.anchorPoint.x;
          pt.y += scene.size.height * scene.anchorPoint.y;
          //pt.x += nodeA.position.x //- nodeA.frame.size.width / 2
          //pt.y += nodeA.position.y

          let joint = SKPhysicsJointPin.jointWithBodyA(nodeA.physicsBody, bodyB: nodeB.physicsBody,
              anchor: pt)*/

          self.physicsWorld.addJoint(joint)
      }
  }
  ```

How should I create this rope so that it doesn't break anymore? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Post the relevant code for the 2 objects and the joint.